# adding characters into a datagrid in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to vb.net. I would like to know how i could i/p a string via textbox and display its individual characters into a datagrid view in diff rows?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Are you only using a single column in the datagridview? if so you could do this easily by stepping through each character in the string and adding a row containing that character... see the code example below

```
InputString = TextBox1.Text
For a = 0 To InputString.Length - 1
    Datagridview1.Rows.Add(InputString(a))
Next
```

Cant see why you'd want to do this though - If this isn't what you're trying to accomplish please give us more details